# Adjust tableView height by code in Swift

Tags: swift, height, tableview, uitableview

I am trying to automatically adjust the table view height in my project, by determining what kind of iPhone the user has. However, I am not quite sure how I would proceed in order to adjust the height. I have tried several methods such as `self.tableView.rowHeight = 100` etc, but with no luck.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Table view constraints]

[image: Table view constraints]

Comment: are you using a UITableViewController or a UIViewController with a tableView that you put there your self ?

Comment: @Ocunidee I am using a tableview that I have put in myself.

Comment: can you show an image of the constraints you put in storyboard or if you've done by code, the snippets?

Comment: @Ocunidee Uploaded two pictures right now. Unfortunately I have not done any constraints by code.

Comment: @Ocunidee In fact, I have also made a constraint connecting the tableView to the bottom as well.

Comment: I don't know where you are trying to adjust the size in your controller, but you should get an IBOutlet of the height constraint. Then you can adjust it this way: heightConstraint.constant = 150 and do a tableView.layoutIfNeeded() after changing the constraint

Comment: if you have a constraint at the bottom then of course, you cannot change the height of the tableview, it is decided bu the top and bottom constraint then. you either pin the top and bottom or pin the top and set a height

Comment: can you upload a screen of the render you have at the moment, and the render you want to have ?

Comment: @Ocunidee I did honestly not know that you could create IBOutlets of constraints, so thanks for learning me something new today! Anyways, I did exactly that - and it resulted in an error. Any idea why? Error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: @LoryHuz Would you mind elaborating for me what you mean by render? :-)

Comment: Screenshot of the actual result for example

Comment: @LoryHuz The tableView displays just fine, the problem is that in each tableView cell - I have put a rounded UIButton - and I don't want the tableView to cut it (so it looks better) - so therefore I want to adjust the height for each iPhone.

Comment: Use the UITableViewAutomaticDimension class. If you have a label inside of the cells

Comment: @askaale, can you edit your post with the code of where you are trying to access the IBOutlet and added it?

Comment: You didn't need to adjust the height of the tableview then, but the height of each cell in this tableView, right ?

Comment: @Lory Huz is right, changing the height of the tableView will not have any effect on the size of each cell

Comment: did you try to override this method ?

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 60 // the height you want
    }

Comment: I see, however - I need to change the height of the tableView itself, as changing the height of each cell will just make the buttons look weird.

Answer (score 1):

First, create an extension to detect which iPhone is running the app:

```
extension UIDevice {
    var iPhone: Bool {
        return UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone
    }
    enum ScreenType {
        case iPhone4
        case iPhone5
        case iPhone6
        case iPhone6Plus
        case unknown
    }
    var screenType: ScreenType {
        guard iPhone else { return .unknown }
        switch UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height {
        case 960:
            return .iPhone4
        case 1136:
            return .iPhone5
        case 1334:
            return .iPhone6
        case 2208:
            return .iPhone6Plus
        default:
            return .unknown
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your controller, link the tableview delegate if you didn't do it yet:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}
```

Implement the delegate method like so to adjust height of cell depending on iphone type:

```
extension YourViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        switch UIDevice().screenType {
        case .iPhone4:
            return 40
        default:
            return 60
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, however - I am really looking for a way to adjust the table view height, not the cell. Anyways, this is brilliant, and thanks for sharing! I appreciate your help!

Comment: you just said the opposite in a previous commentary.. please be more precise of what you need. :)

Comment: I am sorry if I was unclear, what I meant was; if I was to change the height of each tableview cell, the rounded UIButton inside each cell would shrink, and it would not look good. Sorry! :-)

Comment: Link height constraint (IBOutlets), in your view controller, and update its value in viewDidLoad method (you can use the extension to detect the iphone, and adjust for each one). I'll update my answer if it's working

Comment: Thanks! However, I seem to get an error when I set the 'tableViewHeight.constant = 300' when I put it in the viewDidLoad. Any ideas on how I could prevent this from happening?

Comment: what is the error ? did you put your code after "super.viewDidLoad()" ?
Make sure that tableViewHeight is properly linked and not nil

Answer (score 0):

Please this two delegate method of tableview in your view controller

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```